# Navigate from a function call React native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Hi guys I am having trouble finding a solution on my problem because I want to navigate to another page but here's the problem

```
function NewOrderPopUp({id, services, name, rating, accepted, destinationPlaceName, userPlaceName, driverName, driverContactNumber, driverRating, driverTrackingNumber})
{
    async function toggleAcceptBooking()
    {
        await firestore()
        .collection('userBookingRequest')
        .doc(id)
        .update({
            accepted : !accepted,
            driverName: 'Sample Driver',
            driverContactNumber: '09123456789',
            driverRating: '4.9',
            driverPlateNumber: 'NFT-2020',
            driverTrackingNumber: GenerateTrackingNumber(),
        })
        CheckIfBookingAccepted();
    }
}

return (
        <View>....</View>
);

export default NewOrderPopUp;
```

And I am calling the `NewOrderPopUp` Page in another file.
like this

```
import NewOrderPopUp from "../../components/NewOrderPopUp";
const HomeScreen = () => {

//... codes here

return (
<View>
    <FlatList
         horizontal
         contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 30}}
         data={userBookingData}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
         renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp {...item}/>} />                     
</View>
);
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

What I wanted is that if I click the toggleAcceptBooking it will nagivate to another page like

```
navigation.navigate('BookingPage');
```

Can someone enlighten me please . Thank you.

Comment: Add nav script in `CheckIfBookingAccepted()` or after the `firestore()` promise resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it by passing `navigation` down as a prop.

do the following steps.

1. handle navigation prop in `HomeScreen`

```js
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

}
```

2. pass navigation as a prop to `NewOrderPopUp`

```js
<FlatList
    ...
    renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp navigation={navigation} {...item}/>} />
```

3. handle navigation prop in `NewOrderPopUp` and use it to navigate.

```js
function NewOrderPopUp( {navigation, ...} ){
    async function toggleAcceptBooking(){
        await ...
        navigation.navigate('BookingPage');
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') I am having this error

Comment: "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.6",

Comment: please update your question with the code to can find the error.